# What is the significance of the song "Take Me Home, Country Roads"?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-golden-circle

In *Kingsman: The Golden Circle*, Merlin starts singing "Take Me Home, Country Roads" while he is sitting on a land mine. Does the song have any significance, or could he have been singing "Despacito" and have the same result?

Comment: Related:  I first heard this as a cover version titled "Country Road" performed by Maynard Ferguson on his M.F. Horn Two album:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Wf_vd1Bqag

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because [Matthew Vaughn thought he was being clever](https://twitter.com/mikeryan/status/910197927548776448):

> Vaughn thought he was being very clever using John Denver music -- he's not happy he's the fifth movie this year
>
> > Mike Ryan: Speaking of music, John Denver's music plays a big role in this film. We've had a lot of John Denver in movies this year.
> >
> > Matthew Vaughn: Don't wind me up. Fucking hell.
> >
> > Mike Ryan: John Denver music was also in Alien: Covenant, Okja, and Logan Lucky. Why is this happening?
> >
> > Matthew Vaughn: I have no idea and I cannot believe it! **I wrote John Denver into the script two and a half years ago thinking, "No one really talks about John Denver anymore."** Now I think we're the sixth movie using John Denver! Look at the world, we are getting closer and closer to the singularity, whether we like it or not.

Comment: And then the year after Country Roads, Take Me Home features prominently in Fallout 76...

Comment: @Nzall Wouldn't surprise me if they did that on purpose after this interview.

Comment: Sound reasonable. But seem weird an English Kingsman sing an American song as his last song.

Comment: @Mast Certainly not, Fallout 76 is set in West Virginia and Country Roads is one of the official state songs. For decades prior, it was *the* *un*official state song.  That's the same reason it's in Logan Lucky (well, it's more of a joke that it'd be someone from WV's actual favorite song just because of how much it is already played). It is pretty much ubiquitous, played at sporting events more than the national anthem. I can't speak for the popularity elsewhere.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Maybe as weird as Germans singing "Country Roads" during Oktoberfest?

Comment: @DarrenRinger That actually makes a lot more sense, yes.

Comment: @Kyralessa This has nothing to do with the current year being 2022. Nor has it got anything to do with the year we're talking about: 2017. Vaugh already said that he put that song in there ***two and a half years before the movie was released***. Also, people who pick the music for movies don't care about the anniversary of someone's death.